# How do I change the background color of a frame to default?

Tags: beamer

I am dividing a frame into two columns such that one column contains text and the other contains the figure. But, after doing it, the background color of frame gets changed. How do I resolve it?

[image]

```
\begin{frame}{Rotation-invariant code generation and row vector formation}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item The matching performance can be affected by rotation in the input samples 
                    \item 512 column can be considered as 360 degree \cite{encode}
                    \item One column rotation is 360/512 = 0.703125 
                    \item 8 column rotation: 8 $\times$ 0.703125 = 5.625
                    \item IrisCode of size 64 $\times$ 512, difficult to handle rows and column wise 
                    \item Convert it into row vector
                \end{itemize}
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{}
                \begin{figure}[!htp]
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=0.90\textwidth]{Bilder/1.pdf}
                    \caption{Rotation in templates}
                \end{figure}%
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: If you don't like the blue background from the blocks, don't put your content into block?

Comment: If this does not solve your problem, please make a MWE.

Comment: @samcarter the background gets gray when i divide into 2 columns. You can see into the figure. Second, the blue strip is coming over both columns. I need to remove it.

Comment: It't not gray, its light blue (I can show you the definition in the source). But as I have already said, just remove the block, if you don't want it.

Comment: Off-topic, but floating arguments such as `[!htp]` are superfluous in beamer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The light blue background is from the blocks in which you place your content. If you don't want it, just don't use blocks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Rotation-invariant code generation and row vector formation}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
%            \begin{block}{}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item The matching performance can be affected by rotation in the input samples 
                    \item 512 column can be considered as 360 degree \cite{encode}
                    \item One column rotation is 360/512 = 0.703125 
                    \item 8 column rotation: 8 $\times$ 0.703125 = 5.625
                    \item IrisCode of size 64 $\times$ 512, difficult to handle rows and column wise 
                    \item Convert it into row vector
                \end{itemize}
%            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
%            \begin{block}{}
                \begin{figure}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=0.90\textwidth]{example-image}
                    \caption{Rotation in templates}
                \end{figure}%
%            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```